# .net data service OData feed: How to force excel to interprete a column as date without time

Tags: .net, excel, odata, wcf-data-services

[image: Situation in Excel-Screenshot]

Backend is a System.Data.Services.DataService with a hand crafted ODataContext, that provides an IQueryable of MyModelType. The respective fields in the model are typed as nullable DateTime. Interestingly enough, the left column, whose fields are never null is displayed correctly as date only.

Changing the formatting in Excel is just ignored, don't know why.

Is there any magic attribute I could put on my model property, something like [DateOnly] that results in the required behaviour?

Comment: Are you pulling the data through directly the Excel Odata connector or using PowerPivot? Do you have access to PowerPivot?

Comment: Bare Excel. PowerPivot not available. To be honest, I thought the former PowerPivot made it into vanilla Excel when I saw the OData-Feature. Didn't know it is still available.

Comment: Its still a separate add-in in 2013, but it ships with Excel. Try enabling it through the COM add-ins list, that will allow you to run a transform on your column into the format you desire.